# what is the meaning of collapse argument in unnest_tokens function in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, text-mining, tidytext

for example, I know the default setting for collapse in unnest_tokens is TRUE. But I'm confused what's real meaning of collapse argument. I have read through the R documentation, however I still confused.
Here's an example I wrote. Is there any difference for the return value if I change collapse to TRUE?

```r
bigram_freq <- tw %>%
  unnest_tokens(bigram,text,token = "ngrams", n=2, collapse = FALSE)
```

Comment: Since you have your `tw` there, have you run once each with `collapse=TRUE`, once with `collapse=FALSE`, and once with `collapse=NULL` to see what the differences may be?

Comment: what's the help say it means?

Answer (score 0):

The `collapse` argument controls how the input text is handled across new lines:

> Whether to combine text with newlines first in case tokens (such as sentences or paragraphs) span multiple lines.

Check out the difference in behavior with `collapse = TRUE` compared to `collapse = FALSE`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

emily <- tibble(text = c("Because I could not stop for Death -",
                         "He kindly stopped for me -"))

## notice the bigram "death he"
emily %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text, token = "ngrams", n = 2, collapse = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 11 x 1
#>    word          
#>    <chr>         
#>  1 because i     
#>  2 i could       
#>  3 could not     
#>  4 not stop      
#>  5 stop for      
#>  6 for death     
#>  7 death he      
#>  8 he kindly     
#>  9 kindly stopped
#> 10 stopped for   
#> 11 for me

## notice no "death he"
emily %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text, token = "ngrams", n = 2, collapse = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 1
#>    word          
#>    <chr>         
#>  1 because i     
#>  2 i could       
#>  3 could not     
#>  4 not stop      
#>  5 stop for      
#>  6 for death     
#>  7 he kindly     
#>  8 kindly stopped
#>  9 stopped for   
#> 10 for me
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>